# Microsoft Access - Multiple Transactions when Inserting into Remote DB

Tags: sql, ms-access, transactions, vba

I'm currently trying to do multiple inserts from an access database to a remote sql server.  Thus far I've had no luck.  When I attempt to code in a workspace and transactions I receive a data mismatch error, but the functional `insert` works perfectly fine separately.

Here is my code: **Transaction One has been commented out**

```
Private Sub cmdInsSqlSrvr_Click()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

  Dim dbAccess As DAO.Database
  Dim strTableName As String
  Dim strSQL As String
  Dim strSqlServerDB As String
  Dim strTableName2 As String
  Dim cInTrans As Boolean
  Dim wsp As DAO.Workspace


  strTableName = "po_header_sql"
  strTableName2 = "po_line_Sql"

    '<configuration specific to SQL Server ODBC driver>
  strSqlServerDB = "ODBC;DRIVER={SQL Server};" & _
                   "Server=;" & _
                   "DATABASE=;" & _
                   "Uid=;" & _
                   "Pwd=;"


  'Start Transaction One
  'Set dbAccess = DBEngine(0)(0)

 ' strSQL = "INSERT INTO [" & strSqlServerDB & "].TABLE3 SELECT * FROM " & strTableName & ";"
  'dbAccess.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
  'InitConnect = True

  'MsgBox (dbAccess.RecordsAffected & " records have been moved from " & strTableName & " to remote DB")
  'Command9.SetFocus
  'cmdInsSqlSrvr.Enabled = False
  'cmdInsertTbl.Enabled = True

' End Transaction One

 'Begin Transaction Two

  Set wsp = DBEngine(0)(0)
  wsp.BeginTrans
  Set dbAccess = wsp(0)
  cInTrans = True

  strSQL = "INSERT INTO [" & strSqlServerDB & "].TABLE4 SELECT * FROM " & strTableName2 & ";"
  dbAccess.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
  InitConnect = True

  MsgBox (dbAccess.RecordsAffected & " records have been moved from " & strTableName & " to remote DB")
  wsp.CommitTrans
  cInTrans = False
   Command9.SetFocus
   cmdInsSqlSrvr.Enabled = False
   cmdInsertTbl.Enabled = True

'End Transaction Two

ExitProcedure:
  On Error Resume Next
  Set dbAccess = Nothing
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
  InitConnect = False
  MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Moving data to Sql Server failed: Error " & Err.Number
  Resume ExitProcedure

End Sub
```

Comment: Which version of Access are you using, I don't think you can run an "INSERT" statement like this in Access that will insert into a remote database, only in to the local Access database but it won't recognise the table name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by separating the insert statements and putting dbAccess.Execute after each one. Also cleaned up the code substantially.  Code follows:

```
Private Sub cmdInsSqlSrvr_Click()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler

  Dim dbAccess As DAO.Database
  Dim strTableName As String
  Dim strSQL As String
  Dim strSqlServerDB As String
  Dim strTableName2 As String

  strTableName = "po_header_sql"
  strTableName2 = "po_line_Sql"

    '<configuration specific to SQL Server ODBC driver>
  strSqlServerDB = "ODBC;DRIVER={SQL Server};" & _
                   "Server=<server ip>;" & _
                   "DATABASE=<database name>;" & _
                   "Uid=<database uid>;" & _
                   "Pwd=<database password>;"

  Set dbAccess = DBEngine(0)(0)

  strSQL = "INSERT INTO [" & strSqlServerDB & "].TABLE3 SELECT * FROM " & strTableName & ";"
  dbAccess.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

  MsgBox (dbAccess.RecordsAffected & " records have been moved from " & strTableName & " to remote DB")

  strSQL = "INSERT INTO [" & strSqlServerDB & "].TABLE4 SELECT * FROM " & strTableName2 & ";"
  dbAccess.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
  InitConnect = True

  MsgBox (dbAccess.RecordsAffected & " records have been moved from " & strTableName2 & " to remote DB")
   Command9.SetFocus
   cmdInsSqlSrvr.Enabled = False
   cmdInsertTbl.Enabled = True


ExitProcedure:
  On Error Resume Next
  Set dbAccess = Nothing
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
  InitConnect = False
  MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Moving data to Sql Server failed: Error " & Err.Number
  Resume ExitProcedure

End Sub
```